# Failing to tune decision tree classifier parameters using gridsearch

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to tune parameters using GridSearchCV but keep encountering this error message

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter decisiontreeclassifier for estimator DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
            max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
            min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
            min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort=False, random_state=None,
            splitter='best'). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

This is the code I have written

```
accuracy_score = make_scorer(accuracy_score,greater_is_better = True)
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
depth = np.arange(1,30)
leaves = [1,2,4,5,10,20,30,40,80,100]
param_grid =[{'decisiontreeclassifier__max_depth':depth,
             'decisiontreeclassifier__min_samples_leaf':leaves}]
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = dtc,param_grid = param_grid,
                           scoring=accuracy_score,cv=10)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: Use ```max_depth``` instead of ```decisiontreeclassifier__max_depth``` in your ```param_grid```. (The same thing applies to the other parameter.) The notation that you're using is for pipelines with multiple estimators chained together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `max_depth` instead of `decisiontreeclassifier__max_depth` in your `param_grid`. (The same thing applies to the other parameter.) The notation that you're using is for pipelines with multiple estimators chained together.

```
accuracy_score = make_scorer(accuracy_score,greater_is_better = True)
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
depth = np.arange(1,30)
leaves = [1,2,4,5,10,20,30,40,80,100]
param_grid =[{'max_depth':depth,
             'min_samples_leaf':leaves}]
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = dtc,param_grid = param_grid,
                           scoring=accuracy_score,cv=10)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train,y_train)
```